# Image not display in table cells from firebase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

I have a table view,

I have a DB using Firebase fetching some data: title, caption, image.

The titles and captions display perfectly and are being fetched from Firebase. However, none of the images appear . ..

Any help will be amazing please :) :)

The code of my View controller is the following:

```
//
//  Feed.swift
//  MobileAppDemo
//
//  Created by Mikko Hilpinen on 31.10.2016.
//  Copyright © 2016 Mikkomario. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit
import FirebaseAuth
import FirebaseDatabase
import FirebaseStorage
import SwiftKeychainWrapper
import SwiftyJSON

var posts = [Post]()
var selectedIndexPath: Int = 0

class FeedVC: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate, UITableViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var feedTableView: UITableView!

private var readPosts: ObserveTask?

@IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    feedTableView.dataSource = self
    feedTableView.delegate = self

    readPosts = Post.observeList(from: Post.parentReference.queryOrdered(byChild: Post.PROPERTY_CREATED)) {
        observedPosts in

        posts = observedPosts.reversed()
        self.feedTableView.reloadData()
    }
}

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return posts.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell  {
    let cell = self.feedTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MessageCell")! as UITableViewCell

    let messageImageView = cell.viewWithTag(1) as! UIImageView
    let titleLabel = cell.viewWithTag(2) as! UILabel
    let captionText = cell.viewWithTag(3) as! UILabel


    titleLabel.text = posts[indexPath.row].title
    titleLabel.numberOfLines = 0

    captionText.text = posts[indexPath.row].caption
    captionText.numberOfLines = 0


    return cell

}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    selectedIndexPath = indexPath.row
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "push", sender: self)
    self.feedTableView.reloadData()
}
}
```

To call the image I have the follow in me cell.swift

```
  //
 //  MessageCell.swift
 //  MobileAppDemo
 //
 //  Created by Mikko Hilpinen on 31.10.2016.
 //  Copyright © 2016 Mikkomario. All rights reserved.
 //

 import UIKit
 import FirebaseStorage


 class MessageCell: UITableViewCell
 {
 // @IBOutlet weak var profileImageView: UIImageView!
 // @IBOutlet weak var likeButton: UIButton!

 @IBOutlet weak var messageImageView: UIImageView!
 @IBOutlet weak var messageTextView: UITextView!
 @IBOutlet weak var titleTextView: UITextView!
 @IBOutlet weak var linkbutton: UIButton!

 // @IBOutlet weak var likeLabel: UILabel!

private var post: Post!

func configureCell(tableView: UITableView, post: Post)
{
    self.post = post

    // Basic info
  //        self.messageImageView.image = postPic

   messageImageView.image = post.postPic
   titleTextView.text = post.title
    messageTextView.text = post.caption


    // Post user
    User.get(id: post.creatorId)
    {
        postCreator in 




    // Image
    Storage.getImage(with: post.imageUrl)
    {
        postPic in

        self.messageImageView.image = postPic
        // Row height changes so table needs to be reset
        tableView.beginUpdates()
        tableView.endUpdates()
    }
}
```

--

I've updated my feed.swift with the following:

```
    messageImageView.sd_setImage(with: URL(string:"\(posts[indexPath.row].imageUrl)"))
```

using SDWebImage - but im still not having any image being display :(

Answer (score 0):

You're not seeing any images because you never set them.  You need to make a call to `configureCell` within `cellForRowAt`

Comment: hmm, thanks Russel, do you know how can this be achieve ?

Thanks :)

Comment: just make the call within `cellForRowAt` - but your Cell class is a bit odd.  You should not be reloading the `tableView` from within a cell, and you don't need the reference to the `tableView` at all.  Also, you have created outlets for some of the controls you are using, but then you ignore the outlets and access the controls using the tag value.

Comment: Ok, Ill try my best, i starting with ios dev, so i m not sur to be able to do this ehhehe